# Spring boot rabbitmq connection refuse eventhough not having dependency

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

When creating the project from springinitializer, I added rabbitmq dependency but later I remove it after deciding not to use it. Now, I am getting connection refused error only once after I run the application. It does not affect the usage/functionality of the rest api and it works very well but no one wants errors in their apps eventhough it does not cause problems. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and it does not work. It may be related to health check of actuator but could not find a way out. Here is the exception message;

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:510) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:751) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2095) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2068) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2048) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) [spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) [spring-boot-actuator-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_131]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_131]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_131]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_131]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_131]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_131]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1113) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063) ~[amqp-client-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:526) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:473) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to really have removed "spring-boot-starter-amqp" from your pom.xml/build.gradle file.
2. Post your complete dependencies section, so we can find out if there's still another dependency inside which pulls in "messaging".

Comment: I did not know amqp is a part of it. Removing solved the problem. Thanks